# What's the difference between enthymesis (ἐνθύμησις) and ennoia (ἔννοια) as in Heb 4:12?

Tags: word-study, hebrews

Both,`ἐνθύμησις` as well as `ἔννοια`, can be translated as *thought*. So, I am wondering what is the **semantic difference** between the two and in how far do they differ from *dialogismos / διαλογισμός* OR *logismos / λογισμός* (Rom 2:15) OR *dianoema / διανόημα* (Lk 11:17) which are also used in the NT for this notion?

Also in how far is it important for the two to be separated through the work of the *Logos*?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the definitions from BDAG -

**ἐνθύμησις** - the **process** of considering something, *thought, reflection, idea*

**ἔννοια** - the **content** of mental processing, thought, knowledge, insight

Note the important "is" on the end of the first word meaning it is a process rather than a result.  Thus, it appears that ἐνθύμησις is the process by which we arrive at ἔννοια.

Taken together, these almost form a hendiadys of all mental processes and ideas (Paul loved a good hendiadys!) that the Word of God exposes.

Other words such as dialogismos, διαλογισμός, logismos, λογισμός involve the way these internal ideas are expressed or verbalized/communicated to others.  While that is the technically correct meaning, Greek writers were not always quite so precise in their usage.

Comment: wow, great Dottard! Thank you very much. Can it be generally said about "is"-endings in ancient Greek that they refer to some kind of process?

Comment: @JonathanRhein - generally that is true - there are some exceptuon.  Another example is the difference between krisis and krima (judgement).  But that is another question.